# Getting a node's children depending on another children's text

Tags: java, xpath

I want to get the english or hungarian elements' text depending on the title. So far, I came up with this. Can you help me with a cleaner or more professional solution for this using xpath?

The XML:

```
<Textbook>
    <TEXT>
        <Title>SAMPLE TITLE 1</Title>
        <English>Sample english text</English>
        <Hungarian>Sample hungarian text</Hungarian>
    </TEXT>
    <TEXT>
        <Title>SAMPLE TITLE 2</Title>
        <English>Sample english text 2</English>
        <Hungarian>Sample hungarian text 2</Hungarian>
    </TEXT>
</Textbook>
```

The code:

```
public String getResults (String elementName, String language) throws XPathExpressionException {
    xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/Textbook/TEXT/Title");
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        if (nodes.item(i).getTextContent().equals(elementName)) {
            XPathExpression expr2 = xpath.compile("/Textbook/TEXT/" + language);
            NodeList nodes2 = (NodeList) expr2.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            return nodes2.item(i).getTextContent();
        } 
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter `<TEXT>` by it's chld `<Title>` content. For example, this XPath will get `<TEXT>` having child `<Title>` with content equals "SAMPLE TITLE 1" :

```
//TEXT[Title='SAMPLE TITLE 1']
```

So your requirement can actually be fulfilled using single XPath like so :

```
.....
String path = "/Textbook/TEXT[Title='" + elementName + "']/" + language
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(path);
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    return nodes.item(i).getTextContent();
}
.....
```

Comment: Thanks! It was useful for me.